# Update the whole document after specific value

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a contact list based on priority so in code, I called it index.
I want when user but contact on some index then if that index is already given to some contact than get free by add 1 to its index and then that goes till the last document.
I'm using mongoose and node.js
For example, user put a contact on 2 index. so the document on 2 index should be changed to 3 and 4 to 5 and so on.

```
router.post('/addContact', async function(req,res){
    var myData = new contactListSchema(req.body);
    const numDoc = await contactListSchema.countDocuments();
    for (let i = req.body.index; i < (numDoc-req.body.index); i++){
      contactListSchema.updateMany({index:i},{$set:{index:i+1}})
      console.log("Loop Value",i);
     
    }
    console.log("NUmber of Doc",numDoc);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
        console.log("My Data",JSON.stringify(myData));
        myData.save()
        .then(item => {;
            res.status(200).send("Item Saved");
          })
          .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
              });
})
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @D.SM How to do that task ? as above code is not able to perform it